# alternate optimized query of sub query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select * from solar_park where solar_park_uid 
in 
(select distinct solar_park from solar_park_pooling_station where pooling_station 
in
(select distinct pooling_station_uid FROM solar_inverter where solar_generator_uid in (:solarGeneratorUid));
```

I am using this query but for certain reasons i want alter query of this plz help

Comment: Your query has missing closing parenthesis. Moreover you don't need `distinct` inside `IN`. Another alternative of `IN` can be correlated sub-query. Go Ahead and try it.

Comment: can u provide me the code

Comment: not working as good as i am thinking please provide well optimized query

Comment: thanks for the tips i m new in this so dont mind plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative can be to re-write the query as `correlated sub-query` as below.

```
select *
from solar_park sp
where exists (
                select 1 -- * can also be used
                from solar_park_pooling_station spps
                where exists (
                            select 1 -- * can also be used
                            from solar_inverter si
                            where spps.pooling_station = si.pooling_station_uid
                            and sp.solar_park_uid = spps.solar_park
                            and solar_generator_uid IN (:solarGeneratorUid)
                            )
              );
```

You can check tutorial: **[Exists and Not Exists sub-queries in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)**

Hope this will help.

Comment: i don't have enough point to vote your answer when i get i will defiantly do.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below query where table it's left outer join:

```
select * from solar_park  as SP
left outer join (
select distinct solar_park from solar_park_pooling_station
) as SPPS on SPPS.solar_park = SP.solar_park_uid
left outer join (
select distinct pooling_station_uid FROM solar_inverter where solar_generator_uid in (:solarGeneratorUid)
) as  SI on SI.pooling_station_uid= SPPS.pooling_station
where SPPS.solar_park  is not null and SI.pooling_station_uid is not null
```

Comment: but in this no need of left outer join bcz i dont want extra records in this